# CSS: Select every 2nd child but not every 4th

Tags: css, css-selectors, frontend

I need to select every 2nd child of an element but if it is a multiple of 4 (4, 8, 12...) it should not be selected. So the "sequenze" that i want would be [2, 6, 10, 14].

My current solution is:

```
p:nth-child(2n) {
  background: purple;
}
p:nth-child(4n) {
  background: white;
}
```

Now the 2nd, 6th, 10th and 14th elements have a purple background color. But this isn't a fancy way to solve the problem.

Can I somehow combine these two selectors into something like

```
p:nth-child(2n \ 4n) { //Just an idea how this selector could work
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. Your solution is fine. You might want to use `background: inherit` so you don't have to repeat "white".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for your sequence ([2, 6, 10, 14].):

```
   p:nth-child(4n-2) {
      background: purple;
    }
```

```css
p:nth-child(4n-2) {
  background: purple;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 3</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 4</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 5</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 6</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 7</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 8</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 9</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 10</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 11 </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 12</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 13 </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 14 </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 15</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum 16</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
p:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background: purple;
}
```